# Camera View is Blank

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm new to Blender and am having a lot of trouble wit the camera position. I placed it using "Align Active Camera To View", but when I look at the camera view (Numpad 0), I can't see anything except the grid. The same thing happens when I try to render the view. It is grey, not black, and I'm using the default lamp. The shapes shown in the images are cylinders, if that changes anything.

If I spin the camera, I get a very strange view, when I can kind of see the cylinders on the right, but they are cut off. I cannot see anything that should be in the way. In the last picture, the camera is basically at 90 degrees to what I think it should be (4) (see pics).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

[image: Front view]
[image: Side view that shows camera]
[image: Camera Viewpoint set using "Active View"]
[image: Camera Viewport rotated around z-axis showing cylinders]

Comment: Check the camera Clipping distance

Comment: Welcome Anna :) Please check if the link above solves your issue. If not you can leave a comment here. Enjoy the site!

Comment: Thank you so much! What a fantastic community you have here.